# Fill is only filling a part of my plotly graph instead of all of it

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm using plotly on JS to create an interactive plot of a linear regression with its confidence interval. The data is correct and everything is being shown ok, except for the fill function in the interval. Even though the lines are being fully plotted, is only filling a part of the interval instead of all the space between them. Here is the code for my interval:

```
let lower_trace = [];
let top_trace = [];

data.forEach(obj => { 
    lower_trace.push(obj['lower'])
    top_trace.push(obj['upper'])
});

let trace_low = {
    x: x_values,
    y: lower_trace,
    mode: 'lines',
    fill: 'tonexty',
    type: 'scatter',
    name : "low",
    line: {
        color:  '#d4e6f1'
    }
    };

let trace_upper = {
    x: x_values,
    y: top_trace,
    mode: 'lines',
    fill: '',
    type: 'scatter',
    name : "high",
    line: {
        color:  '#d4e6f1'
        }
};


let traceArray = [];
traceArray.push(trace_upper);
traceArray.push(trace_low);

traceArray.push(fit); //Plots the trending line
dots = Object.values(traces);
    dots.forEach(dot =>{
    traceArray.push(dot);   
}); //Plots the data as scatter

let layout = { 
    font: {size: 12},
    xaxis: {
    showgrid: true,
    title: 'PDI',
    },
    yaxis: {
    showgrid: true,
    title: 'Ro',
    },
    legend:{
    x: 1,
    y: 0.5
    }             
};
    
let config = {responsive: true}  
 
Plotly.newPlot('mySidebare', traceArray, layout, config);
```

[This is the plot I'm currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jenFw.png), as you can see, the traces ploted are longer than the space its being actually filled.

I'm trying to get a [plot like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygxaF.png), that fills all the way (I made this plot as a test using matplotlib, but I need to use plotly in my project).

What am I missing??? I'm getting crazy, two hours ago was filling just fine and I didn't even know what I moved or deleted that made it stop working.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE! So if anybody ever comes across this issue, I found the solution here: https://community.plotly.com/t/filled-plot-not-extending-fill-to-y-axis/20749. Turns out if the data its not sorted, plotly gets confused while filling, so all I had to do was to sort the data before plotting it:

```
x_values.sort();
lower_trace.sort();
top_trace.sort();
```

And now [my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2iMi.png) looks like I wanted.